# Powershell to filter user latest last login and last login greater than X number of days

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get AD Users with a last login greater than X number of days, and also retrieve their managers email.

I have searched a lot but not getting what I need, right now below is what I have. It does not filter users with latest login timestamp or not logged on in more than X days.

Once I am able to filter both these attributes I can add the email syntax for each user to send email to their manager.

```
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -Property Name
foreach ($dc in $dcs)
{
$lastlogon = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase  "OU=Sandbox_Users,DC=twi-test,DC=com" -Properties * | Select-Object -Property displayname,lastlogon,samaccountname,EmailAddress,@{Name = "Manager" ; Expression = {(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name}},@{Name = "ManagerEmail" ;`
 Expression = {(Get-ADUser $_.manager -Properties emailaddress).EmailAddress}
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should (in theory) be able to do this by filtering on the lastlogondate field as part of the `get-aduser` command (with a `$days` variable of the X days you want, or just define an integer directly instead):

```
-filter { lastlogondate -lt ((get-date).adddays($days)) }
```

Full code:

```
$days = 7
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -Property Name
foreach ($dc in $dcs) {
     $lastlogon = Get-ADUser -Filter { lastlogondate -lt ((get-date).adddays($days)) } -SearchBase  "OU=Sandbox_Users,DC=twi-test,DC=com" -Properties * |
        Select-Object -Property displayname,lastlogon,samaccountname,EmailAddress,`
            @{Name = "Manager";Expression = {(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name}},`
            @{Name = "ManagerEmail"; Expression = {(Get-ADUser $_.manager -Properties emailaddress).EmailAddress}}
}
```

Per your comment regarding how to get the only the result with the most recent lastlogon result, i'd suggest switching to a `ForEach-Object` loop as you can then pipe the results for further filtering:

```
$days = 7
$dcs | foreach-object {
     Get-ADUser -Server $_ -SearchBase  "OU=Sandbox_Users,DC=twi-test,DC=com" -Properties * |
        Where-Object { $_.LastLogonDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days) } |
        Select-Object -Property displayname,lastlogon,samaccountname,EmailAddress,`
            @{Name = "Manager";Expression = {(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name}},`
            @{Name = "ManagerEmail"; Expression = {(Get-ADUser $_.manager -Properties emailaddress).EmailAddress}}
} | sort lastlogon -desc | select -first 1
```

I just noticed also that in your original code you weren't actually making use of the `$dcs` collection. In this revision i've added a `-server` switch on the first `get-aduser` to make use of it.

Comment: thank you for the response. Since I am querying against all DC's this will give multiple logondate's and how do I filter it will just retrive the latest one. As the logondate does not sync against DC's frequently(I believe 14 days) I just want the lastlogondate which is the most recent one. Also is it possible to use lastlogon as it is replicated regularly and filter the most recent logon and then filter users who did not login in the last 7 days. I still have not executed your query but will try on Monday. Appreciate your time.

Comment: You could add this `| sort lastlogondate | select -first 1`

Comment: In my experience, it tends to be the same across all DCs anyway, but I might be wrong.

Comment: ,  for me sort did not work well with the lastlogon when I tried originally  but I will add these and test the query and let you know how it works. Also I will manually validate some entries to see if the data is returning properly. thanks again.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some additional code on how to get the most recent lastlogon date. I also noticed that in your original code you weren't really making any use of the `$dcs` collection.

Comment: I get an error when running with updated code. I believe it is at the -filter {lastlogondate expresession.  Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: ' lastlogondate -lt ((get-date).adddays($days))' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '20'.
At line:5 char:6
+      Get-ADUser -Server $_ -Filter { lastlogondate -lt ((get-date).adddays($days ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :

Comment: I've revised my answer and moved the lastlogon filter in to a where. I also think there was a logic error in adddays, needed a minus symbol to take the `$days` value away from the current date. I've fixed that too.